# R bar chart count the number of occurences

Tags: r

Some days ago i made a research to a company and now i have to show the results using all type of graphs with r language.

And since i'm a rookie in r, i'm having some doubt using the bar chart.

I have something like this on my excel

```
  XXX;YYY;ZZZ
  XXX;ZZZ
  XXX;YYY;ZZZ
```

And i want to count how many times i get the "xxx" , "yyy" (in this case i should get xxx= 3x and zzz=3x). But for some reason the bar chart counts how many times i have the sequence "XXX;YYY;ZZZ" or the sequence "XXX;ZZZ". there are any function that can help me?

i have just a normal line of code for the graph

```
barplot(table(Food),main = "Distribution", horiz=TRUE, xlab = "Freq", ylab = "Type of food")
```

Thanks

Comment: Make `Food` into `unlist(read.table(text=as.character(Food$V1), sep=";", fill=TRUE, na.strings=""))` then try the `barplot` code again.

Comment: @Rich Scriven Thank you, your solution were correct! Also thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to split up the strings before creating the table. Try

```
barplot(table(unlist(strsplit(Food, ";"))),
    main = "Distribution", horiz=TRUE, xlab = "Freq", ylab = "Type of food")
```

Comment: g5w your solution also worked for me. I really appreciate your explanation and your time. I accepted your comment as the solution to my answer

Comment: I am glad that it helped.